# How can I show the labels of the line in a grouby data plot in pandas , python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to use for loop to plot the Total Order amount of each hour in each city from the total data.
But I only get one plot and I don't know which line belongs to which city in that plot, how can I label those lines in my code?
If possible, I also want to know how I can have one plot for each city instead of having multiple lines in one plot.
Your advice will be much appreciated!

Here are my codes:

```
city_grp=all_data.groupby('city')              # to get the list of the cities

for cty in all_data['city'].unique(): 
    cgroup=city_grp.get_group(cty)             # to get the df of each city group
    h_grp=cgroup.groupby('Hour')               # to group the df by hours
    hs=[h for h,df in h_grp['Quantity Ordered']]
    plt.xticks(hs)
    plt.xlabel('{} Hour in a day'.format(cty))
    plt.ylabel('Quantity Ordered')

    plt.plot(hs,h_grp['Quantity Ordered'].sum())
```

[Here is the plot that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axvu0.png)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for us to experiment with?

Comment: Here is where I downloaded the data _  https://github.com/KeithGalli/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution (with fake data). Basically, you should use the `legend` mehtod.

```
cities = ["New York", "Los Angeles"]
for city in cities:

    p = plt.plot(df.index, df[city])

plt.legend(cities)
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you so much! I added a new row —  plt.legend(all_data['city'].unique())              in my codes and then I can see which line belongs to which city!

Comment: Since it answers your question, do you mind accepting my answer for future generations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

all_data.groupby(["city","Hour"])['Quantity"].sum().unstack().plot()

You may need one more groupby().

See example here https://cmdlinetips.com/2020/05/fun-with-pandas-groupby-aggregate-multi-index-and-unstack/

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer helps me imporve that codes so much！Now I only need two rows of codes to accomplish the plot I want:                                                                                   OR = all_data.groupby(['Hour','city'])['Quantity Ordered'].sum()
OR.unstack().plot()